# помогите найти ошибку в popupmenu

Tags: android, popupmenu

после того, как добавила popupmenu к item-у menu, приложение не грузится.

popup_menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/lightTheme"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/lightTheme"
    android:checkable="false"
     />
<item
    android:id="@+id/darkTheme"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/darkTheme"
    android:checkable="false"/>
```

menu_main.xml

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/themes"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:title="@string/themes"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:onClick="showPopup" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/share"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:title="@string/share"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:checkable="false"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/rate_app"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:title="@string/rate_app"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    android:checkable="false"/>
```

```
  @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.themes:
            showPopup(item.getActionView());
            break;
        case R.id.share:
            Toast.makeText(this, "v razrabotke", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.rate_app:
            Toast.makeText(this, "v razrabotke", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}




  public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popupTheme = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popupTheme.setOnMenuItemClickListener((PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener) this);
    popupTheme.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
    popupTheme.show();
}
```

логи

```
08-07 00:24:11.752 18343-18343/rrrrr.rrrrr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: rodionova.lyubov.reminder, PID: 18343
    android.view.InflateException: Couldn't resolve menu item onClick handler showPopup in class rodionova.lyubov.reminder.MainActivity
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:253)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:481)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:529)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:205)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:127)
        at rodionova.lyubov.reminder.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:82)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2926)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:364)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454)
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5977)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:801)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: showPopup [interface android.view.MenuItem]
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:624)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:603)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$InflatedOnMenuItemClickListener.<init>(SupportMenuInflater.java:249)
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.setItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:481) 
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater$MenuState.addItem(SupportMenuInflater.java:529) 
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.parseMenu(SupportMenuInflater.java:205) 
        at android.support.v7.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(SupportMenuInflater.java:127) 
        at rodionova.lyubov.reminder.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:82) 
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2926) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:364) 
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93) 
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:332) 
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:93) 
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454) 
        at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:55) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5977) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:940) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:801)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обработчик нажатия элемента меню, декларированный в xml атрибутом `android:onClick="showPopup"` должен быть публичный метод `Activity` с указанным именем и единственным параметром типа `MenuItem`:

```
public void showPopup(MenuItem item) {...}
```

И выберите что-то одно - либо атрибут и метод, либо обработка этого элемента в `onOptionsItemSelected`